# BLE Device disconnect event delay

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, android-ble

I have a problem with BLEdevice - android BLE stack does not reports about its disconnect for about 15 seconds after device was disbled. Actual disconnect event appears on timeout, as I can see. Is there any way to notify android that device disappears? My app code is pretty standard, something like this:

```
 private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {


            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {

                .....
            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                // I placed breakpoint at this line and don't see any events for a long time.
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hey! Did you solve the problem? Same here.

Comment: @Mikhail No, unfortunately. In depth: android sets connection timeout to 15-20 secs starting with 6.0 (IOS sets it to about 800 ms). The only way to reduce waiting time is to send ACL_DISCONNECT from ble device before turning off. It won't work if device came offline unexpectedly, but may help when you just disable it within ble range.